# Trouble implementing Meteoric (Meteor-Ionic) package -- Ionic styling not showing up

Tags: javascript, meteor, ionic-framework, meteoric

I want to create a Meteor app that implements the Meteoric package, enabling me to use Ionic UI features. Going off of this: https://github.com/meteoric/meteor-ionic/blob/master/GUIDE.md I'm trying to simply get it to use Ionic styling but it doesn't work. It Meteoric does render the HTML correctly, though.

router.js

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});

Router.route('/', {
    name: 'timeLists'
});
```

layout.html

```
<template name="layout">
{{#ionBody}}
    {{> ionNavBar}}
    {{#ionNavView}}
        {{> yield}}
    {{/ionNavView}}
{{/ionBody}}
</template>
```

timeLists.html

```
<template name="timeLists">
{{#ionContent}}
        Hello.
{{/ionContent}}
</template>
```

What am I missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Solution: I needed to include the Ionic styles in my app's stylesheet:

```
@import '.meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/packages/meteoric_ionic-sass/ionic';
@import '.meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/packages/meteoric_ionicons-sass/ionicons';
```

Comment: I am having the same problem. Where exactly do you paste those two lines? In some css file in your app? But shouldn't Your example run without having any css file in your app?

Comment: They go in to an SCSS file. (Example: https://github.com/meteoric/contacts/blob/master/client/stylesheets/app.scss) The app was functioning but was missing all the styles and cool UI stuff Ionic does, because I wasn't including the Ionic stylesheets in my app's stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

As shown in this [official example](https://github.com/meteoric/contacts/blob/master/client/stylesheets/app.scss) you really need to import styles

```
@import '.meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/packages/meteoric_ionic-sass/ionic';
@import '.meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/packages/meteoric_ionicons-sass/ionicons';
```