# Sizing on the mobile device

Tags: meteor, meteoric

Although I can view meteoric demo pages hosted on meteor, [all components demo](http://meteor-ionic.meteor.com), [a contacts app](http://meteoric-contacts.meteor.com), on chrome on my android mobile device, I cannot view my Meteor + Ionic app (by use of meteoric:ionic package from atmosphere.js) correctly sized on this same device. Navbar is very narrow in y-axis, so for tabs, dialogs etc.

I can view it normally on a desktop browser, even when resized.

I have imported the lines as stated in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28734787/trouble-implementing-meteoric-meteor-ionic-package-ionic-styling-not-showin).

Am I missing some points or this is an issue? If I miss, what is it?

my-app.scss:

```
/* CSS declarations go here */

/* $loading-font-size: 22px; */

@import '.meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/packages/meteoric_ionic-sass/ionic';
@import '.meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/packages/meteoric_ionicons-sass/ionicons';
```

my-app.js:

```
    if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Router.configure({
      layoutTemplate: 'AppLayout'
    });

    Router.route('/', function(){
        this.render('tabs');
    });  
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

my-app.html:

```
<head>
  <title>evbul-ionic</title>
</head>

<body>

</body>

<template name="AppLayout">

  {{#ionBody}}
    {{> ionNavBar}}

    {{#ionNavView}}
        {{>yield}}
    {{/ionNavView}}
  {{/ionBody}}

</template>

<template name="tabs">
  {{#ionTabs class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-top"}}
    {{> ionTab title="News" path="news" iconOff="ios-paper" iconOn="ios-paper"}}
    {{> ionTab title="Todos" path="todos" iconOff="checkmark-circled" iconOn="checkmark-circled"}}
    {{> ionTab title="Profile" path="profile" iconOff="person" iconOn="person"}}
  {{/ionTabs}}
</template>
```

Comment: Does the app work normally when you run it on your desktop browser? And are you importing the css as pointed out on the other SO question, or from ionic's cdn? I have to use the cdn to import my css, but when you then run that on your phone, cordova will block it unless you explicitly give it permission to access the ionic cdn.

Comment: Yes, it works normally in desktop browser, even when resized. By importing the css, do you mean the @import form .meteor dir in the my-app.css?

Comment: updated question according to behaviour in desktop.

Comment: there is a problem with @import path, path does not exist. there is actually `.meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/packages/meteoric_ionic-sass/_ionic.scss` and a dir `.meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/packages/meteoric_ionic-sass/stylesheets/`.

Comment: @Elizer Steinbock, actually how can I now it is not retrieved from the cdn. Also I have downloaded the demo, contacts etc demo apps'  code and built them locally and can view in the  mobile and desktop browsers.